# How to get the excel column header name based on column index in c#

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, devexpress-wpf

I have below code to get the used range from excel sheet.

```
DevExpress.Spreadsheet.Range myRange = mySheet.GetUsedRange();
            myRange = myRange.Exclude(mySheet.Range["A1:T2"]);
```

In above line, exclude range is hard coded which is nothing but right most column header from getUsedRange.
so I want to get is programmatically.
so inside myRange, I can see the there is one property called ModelRange which shows value like {A1:T1999} and There is TopRight property inside ModelRange property which is having value {T2}.

so, all I want here is fetching the right most column header name. in this case it would be T.

Can anyone suggest, how to get it.

Thanks in advance.